# Using ": number" while declaring variables

Tags: c++, enums

If i declare an enum as follows:

```
typedef enum A
{
    a = 0x00000001,
    b = 0x00000002
} AObj;
```

Now if i declare a variable of AObj as follows what does this mean?

```
AObj myAObj : 2;
```

Comment: Did you try and compile that at all?

Comment: ya sorry, i guess i had to put a , :)

Comment: you may aswell fix the missing "=" while you are at it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a way of specifying the number of bits used.
That is 2 means 2 bits.

Also note that this is only useful when used with other bit fields in the same struct as alignment and padding will cause the memory to be skipped.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably talking about "[bit fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field)" which enables you to create a struct in which you can address individual bits. But (unless I am mistaken!) your syntax is all wrong: you are missing commas and equals signs in your enum:

```
    typedef enum A
    {
       a = 0x00000001,
       b = 0x00000002
    } AObj;
```

More importantly, bitfields are declared inside of `struct`s, so it's not entirely clear what you're trying to do.

(Or is this use of the colon some other syntax I'm not aware of???)

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, actually i had to put a ',' not ';' inside the enum. And i guess the answer given down is what i was seraching for.